# CSRF token generation

Tags: csrf

This is a question about generating CSRF tokens.

Usually I'd like to generate a token based off of a unique piece of data associated with the user's session, and hashed and salted with a secret key.

My question is in regards to generating tokens when there is NO unique user data to use. No sessions are available, cookies are not an option, IP address and things of that nature are not reliable.

Is there any reason why I cannot include the string to hash as part of the request as well?
Example pseudocode to generate the token and embed it:

```
var $stringToHash = random()
var $csrfToken = hash($stringToHash + $mySecretKey)
<a href="http://foo.com?csrfToken={$csrfToken}&key={$stringToHash}">click me</a>
```

Example server-side validation of the CSRF token

```
var $stringToHash = request.get('key')
var $isValidToken = hash($stringToHash + $mySecrtKey) == request.get('csrfToken')
```

The string being used in the hash would be different on each request. As long as it was included in each request, the CSRF token validation could proceed. Since it is new on each request and only embedded in the page, outside access to the token would not be available. Security of the token then falls to the $mySecretKey being known only to me.

Is this a naive approach? Am I missing some reason why this cannot work?

Thanks

Comment: The proposed solution is vulnerable to replay attacks. The same token and key combination will work indefinitely.

Comment: Good point, @Matthew. But how we can be defended from case, when token was generated by server, but user did not visit our server back and it was done by hacker with same sessionId+hash? Or it is impossible (without to comparing ip-address/useragent and etc?)

Comment: Oh, `hash(payload + key)` is vulnerable to a [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). If you must, use HMAC for this purpose. @Nigrimmist, specify an expiration time and incorporate it into the token.

Answer (score 29):

*Is there any reason why I cannot include the string to hash as part of the request as well?*

CSRF tokens have two parts. The token embedded in the form, and a corresponding token somewhere else, be it in a cookie, stored in a session or elsewhere. This use of elsewhere stops a page being self contained.

If you include the string to hash in the request, then the request is self contained, so copying the form is all an attacker needs to do, as they have both parts of the token, and thus there is no protection.

Even putting it in the form URL means that it's self contained, the attacker simply copies the form and the submission URL.

Comment: No you don't. One half could be kept in session, or it could be dropped via a cookie. It doesn't have to be stored on the server at all, usually it's cookie based so you don't have to rely on enabling sessions.

Comment: According to OWASP, this is only a *mitigation* called "double submit cookies" https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookies

Comment: Can you explain this "If you include the string to hash in the request, then the request is self contained, so copying the form is all an attacker needs to do, as they have both parts of the token, and thus there is no protection."?

Answer (score 9):

Try `base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))`.
https://github.com/codeguy/php-the-right-way/issues/272#issuecomment-18688498 and I used it for my form example in https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/5668195

Answer (score 2):

I think the best idea to make hash based on HMAC, i.e. make hash encrypted by some password this sequence: username+user_id+timestamp. Each request the hash must be different, timestamp must be if you don't want to get simple replay the hash in attack.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF token meant to prevent (unintentional) data modifications, which are usually applied with POST requests.

Thus, you must include CSRF token for each request that changes data (either GET or POST request).

> My question is in regards to
>   generating tokens when there is NO
>   unique user data to use. No sessions
>   are available, cookies are not an
>   option, IP address and things of that
>   nature are not reliable.

Then simply create a unique user id for each visitor.
Include that id in a cookie or in the URLs (if cookies are disabled).

*Edit:*

Consider the following event:

You have logged-in to your facebook account and then entered to some arbitrary website.

In that website there's a form that you submit, which tells your browser to send a POST request to your facebook account.

That POST request may change your password or add a comment etc, because that the facebook application recognized you as a registered & logged-in user. (unless there's another blocking mechanism, like CAPTCHA )

Comment: Adding part of the token to a URL, and having the other half in the form means no protection at all.

Comment: Sure you did, "Include that id in a cookie or in the URLs (if cookies are disabled)." - you say to put the id in the URL, this simply isn't secure.

Comment: I can't find any better idea how to store a session id when cookies are disabled.

Comment: Ah you meant put the session ID in the URL, and then keep half of the CSRF token in the session? When you were talking about the unique user ID I thought you mean the unique value used to generate the token. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You simply just need the same "token" in the URL/form and in the cookie. This means that you could have your page setting the token cookie to whatever it wants to (preferably some random value) by JavaScript and then just pass the very same value in all requests that goes to your server (as a URI ?param or form-field). No need to have your server generating the cookie.

This is safe as long as we trust that the browser doesn't allow pages from a domain to edit/read cookies for other domains, and this is assumed to be quite secure today.

Having your server generating the token will assume that this token can be safely transmitted to your browser without being picked up by any CSRF attempts (why take the risk?). Though you could put more logic into a server generated token, but to prevent CSRF there is no need.

(If I'm wrong here please let me know)

Answer (score 1):

I wanna say your approach works, because CSRF attack is the attacker utilizing victim's browser to forge a logged-in status, why can they do so? because on most server side the session check is based on a SessionID in cookie, and cookie is a piece of data will be automatically attached to a HTTP request sent to server.

Therefore, there are two key factors for defending CSRF

1. Generate a challenge token, and require client to pass it to server in a non-cookie way, either URL param or POST form is ok.
2. Keep the token safe as what you did to the SessionID, for instance, using SSL.

I recommend reading  [CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple implementation of CSRF token. The key thing is whether this csrf token is generated on the client side or server side. Because the implementation changes drastically for these two scenarios and the entropy of the token as well.

For server side, SecureRandom is the preferred way but in your case you want to generate the CSRF token before any user is identified, [window.crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) provides this functionality where you can generate a *unguessable enough* string to be used for CSRF token.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of CSRF token we can sure incoming request is authenticated (know user not hacker)

**Please note i have required below approach but google can't help me even on stackoverflow i did't get mentioned code below but after collection of stackoverflow answer i have made my day. So it's useful for further searching/ specially for beginners**

I have described below Spring MVC with Spring Interceptor

**Note - I have used google cache to store salt in cache for re verification**

below dependency need to add pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>28.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

below HandlerInterceptorAdapter implemention

```java
    package com.august.security;

    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

    import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
    import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;

    public class CsrfSecurity extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
        List<String> urlList= new LinkedList<>();
        private static final String CSRF_TAG = "CSRF-CHECK";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handleer)
                throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Inside Pre Handler");

            String reqUrl = request.getRequestURI().toString();
            System.out.println("Request URL : " + reqUrl);
            String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
            if (ipAddress == null) {
                ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
            }
            //local host url http://localhost:8080/august/
            if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/august/")) {
                System.out.println("pre handler return true");
                //it will return and next executed postHandelr method
                //because of on above url my webApplication page working
                return true;
            }
            if (ignoreUrl().contains(request.getRequestURI())) {
                System.out.println("inside ignore uri");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("CSRF Security intercepter preHandle method started.......");
                String salt = request.getParameter("csrfPreventionSalt");
                HttpSession sessionAttribute = request.getSession();
                Cache<String, Boolean> csrfPreventionSalt = (Cache<String, Boolean>) sessionAttribute
                        .getAttribute("csrfPreventionSalt");
                if (csrfPreventionSalt == null) {
                    System.out.println("Salt not matched session expired..");
                    parameterValuesPrint(request, "saltCacheNotFound");
                    response.sendRedirect("error");
                    return false;
                } else if (salt == null) {
                    parameterValuesPrint(request, "noSaltValue");
                    System.out.println("Potential CSRF detected !! inform ASAP");
                    response.sendRedirect("error");
                    return false;
                } else if (csrfPreventionSalt.getIfPresent(salt) == null) {
                    System.out.println("saltValueMisMatch");
                    System.out.println("Potential CSRF detected !! inform ASAP");
                    response.sendRedirect("error");
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("csrfPreventionSalt", csrfPreventionSalt);
                }
                return true;
            }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                ModelAndView modelAndView) {
            System.out.println("Inside post Handler");
            System.out.println("CSRF Security key generator method started");
            try {
                //localhost url http://localhost:8080/august/
                //api is my controller path so no need to genrate token for api
                if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/august/api/")) {
                    System.out.println("No need to genrate salt for api");
                } else {
                    HttpSession sessionAttribute = request.getSession();
                    Cache<String, Boolean> csrfPreventionSaltCache = (Cache<String, Boolean>) sessionAttribute
                            .getAttribute("csrfPreventionSalt");
                    System.out.println("csrfPreventionSaltCache ::: " + csrfPreventionSaltCache);
                    if (csrfPreventionSaltCache == null) {
                        csrfPreventionSaltCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(5000)
                                .expireAfterWrite(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("csrfPreventionSaltCache", csrfPreventionSaltCache);
                    }

                    String salt = RandomStringUtils.random(20, 0, 0, true, true, null, new SecureRandom());
                    System.out.println("csrfPreventionSalt genrated ::: " + salt);
                    csrfPreventionSaltCache.put(salt, Boolean.TRUE);
                    if (modelAndView != null) {
                        System.out.println("Model and view not null and salt is added in modelAndView");
                        modelAndView.addObject("csrfPreventionSalt", salt);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
                throws Exception {
            System.out.println("afterCompletion : ");
            if (ex != null) {
                System.out.println("exception : " + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private List<String> ignoreUrl() {
            if(urlList == null) {
                urlList.add("/august/error");
                //add here your ignored url.
            }
            return urlList;
        }

        private void parameterValuesPrint(HttpServletRequest request, String err) {
            StringBuilder reqParamAndValue = new StringBuilder();
            Enumeration<?> params = request.getParameterNames();
            while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
                Object objOri = params.nextElement();
                String param = (String) objOri;
                String value = request.getParameter(param);
                reqParamAndValue = reqParamAndValue.append(param + "=" + value + ",");
            }
            System.out.println(CSRF_TAG + " " + err + "RequestedURL : " + request.getRequestURL());
        }
    }
```

Below is Interceptor registration with spring context

```java
package com.august.configuration;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    import com.august.security.CsrfSecurity;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.august")
    public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            //viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return viewResolver;

        }

        @Bean
        public CsrfSecurity csrfSecurity() {
            return new CsrfSecurity();
        }
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new CsrfSecurity());
        }
    }
```

below is my controller

```java
    package com.august.v1.appcontroller;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @Autowired 
        HttpSession httpSession;

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index(Model model) {
            httpSession.invalidate();
            System.out.println("Home page loaded");
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

below is my index.jsp jsp page

```java
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
         //don't forget to add isELIgnored="false" on old(version) jsp page because of i 
         //have wasted 1 hour for this
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>ADS Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>${csrfPreventionSalt}</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfPreventionSalt" value=${csrfPreventionSalt}>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For Understanding about CSRF - [CSRF explanation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

CSRF utilizes the user's session, so, if you don't have one, there is no CSRF.

Comment: Although this answer is not helpful at all, it is technically correct.