# How to make sure requests are from my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some smartass people are using my api-centric web app to clone my service and make it appear like their own. Is there a way to make sure all ajax requests are for/from my website?

Sure I could use the referrer header but they could easily fake it.

Comment: How are they cloaning it? The only way I can think of for you to secure it is to use ssl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to secure JSON call without using a captcha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444608/how-to-secure-json-call-without-using-a-captcha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a cookie on the client when it hits your site, before it sends any Ajax requests.

Then validate the cookie when serving the Ajax.

Or alternatively you could make your Ajax requests POST only. This way they are subject to the same origin policy.

It will break the whole restful ideology though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: security > ideology, though POST for this purpose bugs me too.

Comment: I guess jQuery's `JSONP` will work around this `same-origin` restriction and keep getting data as usual.

Comment: Is it possible to deny the `JSONP` requests?

Comment: I am afraid not. The first option suggested here should work (Setting / validating) cookie.

Comment: @Hermione using the first method (a Cookie) will not be subject to the JSONP vulnerability.

Comment: The cookie solution might not work if the offending site loads yours in a hidden frame though…

Comment: @DidierL see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed if you need to prevent being framed.

Comment: I think those solutions might only be applicable when javascript is enabled and you set the cookie via javascript. I don't think even the `X-Frame-Options: deny` would block cookies set via the HTTP headers.

Comment: @DidierL designing for the 1% of people with JavaScript disabled, is like designing for people who use IE 5.

Comment: The offending site could use some tricks to disable the JS within the iframe. On IE, just use `<iframe security="restricted"...>`. On other browsers, there are solutions that involve tricking the XSS filter so that it won't execute specific JavaScript elements.

Comment: @DidierL, ok so only set the cookie check if JavaScript is enabled. You could do this by either setting the cookie with JavaScript, or getting JavaScript to redirect to a unique URL to set the cookie. If you have a specific problem you are trying to overcome. Ask it in a new question rather than arguing your point in comments.