# Is it safe to display a image using $_GET for path?

Tags: php, security

Is it safe to display a image using $_GET for path? 
For example using this format: image.php?path=/images/example.jpg

Comment: at least urlencode() the path and image name, the whitespaces and other characters can mess things up in some browsers

Comment: `image.php?path=/../../../../etc/passwd` may be a problem if the php script just blindly processes the path.

Comment: then for url I could use image.php?path=example.jpg
and on php script I can do this: $image = "/images/".$_GET["path"];

Comment: @morandi3 which in my example would turn into `$image="/images//../../../../etc/passwd` and possibly send the password file.

Comment: hmm, yes, you are right

Comment: A solution would be to define an array on php code with allowed values.

Comment: Rule #1: **Don't trust user input**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, just make sure you use `isset` so that it doesn't throw undefined index if someone fiddles with your URL, also you need to check whether the path is valid else show some other image, like image not found by writing text in `alt` attribute

```
if(isset($_GET['index'])) {
   echo '';  
}
```

Points to be looked for:-

- Anybody can tinker URL
- You'll have to sanitize the value
- Often path's will be changed so be sure you use `alt` text if image is not found
- If you don't sanitize, will lead to easy intrusion for hackers

> Inshort I suggest you ***NOT TO DO SO***

Answer (score 2):

Its perfectly safe if you check the path exists after using `basename($_GET['path'])` on the file name, also define your path to the images folder.

Then check that it is an image with `getimagesize($path)`. If any fail, change the filename to a not found image or such.

```
<?php 
$path_to_images = '/images/';
$not_found_img  = './path/to/not_found_image.jpg';

// check path is set and not empty
if(empty($_GET['path'])){
    $path = $not_found_img;
}else{
    $path = $path_to_images.basename($_GET['path']);

    // check that image exists
    if(!file_exists($path)){
        $path = $not_found_img;
    }else{
        //Check if image
        if($img_size = getimagesize($path)) {
            //alls good $path validated
        }else{
            $path = $not_found_img;
        }
    }
}

// do somthing with your $path
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Completely yes.** There are no problems, hackers can't give there bad code, what can hack your page or work with your database. But take care on some other elements.

Comment: Luckily, [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) [only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526522/csrf-cross-site-request-forgery-attack-example-and-prevention-in-php) affects visitors :)