# Java HttpClient accessing image with session id

Tags: java, http, authentication, httpclient

I'm trying to access an image through a url. The problem is I have to be authenticated via a session id to access the image. I'm trying to get authenticated but I'm getting a 403. Also, how would I add my session id and other information after being authenticated to grab the input stream of the image? Here is my attempt:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://cloud.openalpr.com/account/login/");
List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","user"));
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, Consts.UTF_8);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X ...");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

This server requires others fields: csrfmiddlewaretoken and next. See in below image extracted from site https://cloud.openalpr.com/account/login/

[image]

In this way you must does:

```
List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","user"));
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrfmiddlewaretoken", "xxxxxxx"));
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("next", ""));
```

Comment: Hmm I see do you by any chance know how to generate a csrf middleware token ?

Comment: I recommend that do a crawl before of start this requisition. Generate the same value in client-side and server-side is too small probable.

Comment: More information about csrf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805838/csrf-token-generation

Comment: Is it even possible to grab the csrf token from the form?

Comment: yes! A way is to do the first request only to get csrf value using regex. After continue with your code

Comment: everytime I send a request the server will generate a new csrf token